# Promise resolves to null when resolving this

Tags: node.js, promise

I have a function that connects to a API. That function returns a Promise. I can't figure out why Promise.resolve returns null when I'm resolving with a constant containing the `this` context.

```
const connect = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Gitana.connect(config, function(err) {
      const platform = this;
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      console.log(platform) // Object that I want
      resolve(platform)
    });
  });
}

connect()
  .then(platform => {
    console.log(platform) // null
  })
```

I don't know if it is any help but I know there is a method on the resolve object (platform) called datastore. If I resolve that method, ie `resolve(platform.datastore)` I get the method, instead of `null`

I have tried to resolve static values, `resolve(25)` or `resolve('hello')` and that works fine.

**How do I return/resolve the object?**

Comment: This really puzzles me :-D Could it be that that 'this' reference inside the `Gitana.connect` callback is being garbage collected? Could you try to declare a top level variable `let platform = {initial: true}` and then, inside the callback, assign it to the 'this' binding: `platform = this`, before the resolve?

Comment: @Sergeon Unfortunately it's still `null`

Comment: In the worst case, if you cannot find any other solution, you can do a deep clone of the object using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this))`.

Comment: @Vasan That just returns a empty object `{}`

Comment: Yes. It's a object containing methods

Comment: What you describe should not be possible using a proper promise implementation. There is nothing that could change an object reference to `null`.

Comment: You're looking at the implementation. I can't see what's wrong with it

Comment: @Bergi Actually, it is possible, and it looks like OP found the reason!

Comment: @JLRishe Oops, I should've thought of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've noted, it looks like this is happening because the value you're trying to pass actually has a `.then` method, so it is being subsumed in the promise resolution procedure.

One way to pass it without deleting methods would be to wrap it in a container to transport it along:

```
const connect = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Gitana.connect(config, function(err) {
      const platform = this;
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      resolve({ platform });
    });
  });
}

connect()
  .then(({ platform }) => {
    console.log(platform)
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that `platform`, the object to resolve, also has a `then` method. If you resolve the original promise with a new promise then it will try to resolve the new one as well. In this case the new promise resolves to `null`.

```
const connect = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Gitana.connect(config, function(err) {
      const platform = this;
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      delete platform.this;
      resolve(platform);
    });
  });
}
```

The next question is how to do this in a better way than deleting every obsolete `then` method.

Comment: Do you have any idea why it contains a `then` method? Is there any API documentation on this object?